# Need help installing windows over ubuntu (17.10)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, uninstall

as it mentions in the title I'm trying to install windows over my version of ubuntu. I already have a .iso file for windows and a USB, but not sure how to make the USB bootable on ubuntu since on windows it was easy through rufus. Also what would I need to do to install windows onto my hdd to replace ubuntu already on it.
Thanks

*edit* Still in need of help, please.

Answer (score 0):

first download `unetbootin` from [unetbootin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unetbootin) which is batter S/W  for making bootable USB from Ubuntu, download it and make bootable usb with it.
after shutdown your machine,

---

1 Goto BIOS and enable USB booting.

---

2 At boot menu give first priority to USb device

OR

select USB device at startup of machine. select you pandrive and  start your win installer

---

done.

Comment: Link you posted doesn't work for me, found something with same name on ubuntu software though, that work?  @hingu Devang

Comment: When I tried installing it from ubuntu software requires running 'dpkg --configure -a' which then requires sudo and says something about disabling UEFI secure boot.

Comment: is this something that I should do to continue with the instructions? Sorry new to linux stuff.

Comment: When I did attempt this it ran into an error (extremely long with this being the end, however can post the rest in different comments etc if needed)



'Errors were encountered while processing:
 libopenal-data
 libopenal1:amd64
 libopenal1:i386
 libwine:amd64
 libwine:i386
 wine-staging-amd64
 wine-stable-amd64
 wine-stable
 wine32:i386
 wine-staging
 wine-stable-i386:i386
 wine-staging-i386:i386
 wine64
 winehq-staging
 playonlinux'

Answer (score 0):

The best-supported would be to find a Windows machine and use it to make the USB drive bootable (there are lots of answers online covering how to do this, I personally use `diskpart` but that's a rather advanced method).

Once you've managed to boot off the install image, do the following:

1. Select your keyboard, etc. on the first few screens.
2. Select that you want to install a clean copy of Windows, not do an upgrade (if asked).
3. When it asks what partition to install Windows to, click Advanced, then select all of the Ubuntu partitions and delete them, clicking through any warnings you get (**this will permanently delete all data on your hard disk**, I assume you're OK with this and have backed up anything you want to keep to another drive).
4. You should end up with a drive composed only of unallocated space; select this space as where to install Windows (you don't need to manually create any partitions; the installer will do that for you with a pretty reasonable partitioning scheme).
5. From this point the install is mostly unattended until it's time to set up your account; just follow the rest of the prompts to get set up.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. I did this a few hours ago.

1. Don't use Unetbootin -- it's used to make bootable Linux USBs.
2. Use WinUSB -- [here's a guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/make-bootable-windows-10-usb-install.html).

Basically

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install woeusb
```

Comment: during the last line of this I ran into an error that I have posted in one of my other posts on this forum, having to do with dpkg.

Comment: @JustinN. Seems you're unable to install software. I suggest you start by solving that issue and then return to this question.